# PHP form not displaying errors and not reloading google recaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to implement a form to display errors when certain fields for validation alongside a recaptcha box.

My issue is when recaptcha is not set email and name errors show and when recaptcha is set any email or name errors are not showing. Also on clicking the submit button if there are any errors the recaptcha box doesnt show on reload? as well as the page scrolling back to the top section (using scrollify.js) but that i feel is a different problem entirely

any help would be greatly appreciated

I have the isset function on post submit and $res['success'] to prevent the recaptcha error displayig on the page load

formphp is as follows

```
<?php

function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => 'secret',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';

    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

$name_error = $email_error = "";
$name = $email = $message = $sent = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit']) AND (!$res['success'])) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA wasn't checked
    echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.</p><br>';
} else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
        $name_error = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
    } else {

        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email_error = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' ){
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $to = 'gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
        $headers = 'From:' . $email . "\n" . 'Reply-to: ' . $email . "\n"  ;
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            $sent = "Message sent";
            $name = $email = $message = '';
        }
    }
}
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

html for form

```
    <div class="grey">
            <div class="container-contact">
                <form id="contact" method="post">
                    <div id="column-contact-left">
                    <div class='contact-logo'></div>
                    <h3>Contact the Devon Food Movement</h3>
                    <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                        <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name1" value="<?= $name ?>" >

                    </fieldset>
                    <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                    <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                        <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >

                    </fieldset>
                    <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="column-contact-right">
                    <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                        <textarea id="field-no-ui" placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" value="<?= $message ?>" tabindex="3" ></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfJtkcUAAAAAE_7Ob_7BVMkaZMXX-dH-V6uqjCn" ></div>
                    <span class="success"><?= $sent; ?></span>
                    <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since your code is a hazard of bad indents and mixed up conditional blocks, its no wonder you are having a problem. If you clean that mess up, you will see where the problem is happening.

Comment: Also since you didnt provide the html portion, the second question of why recaptcha doesnt show up on reload, is impossible to discern.

Comment: @IncredibleHat could you please elaborate on what you mean bybad intents and conditional blocks as I am new to php. Thanks

Comment: @PaulStephenDavis your PHP code is totally unreadable because you did not indent your code correctly. I edited now so it will be readable as soon as my edit is through the peer review.

Comment: @Cashbee thank you i accepted it, I stupidly spaced it out to make it easir to read, thanks

Comment: @Cashbee so the code is generally okay? I thought that Incrediblehats comment was that what I had written was all wrong?

Comment: I did not "read" your code, and did not try to understand what it does / where the error is. What i can tell you is that the error does not come from falsely-placed brackets. What Incrediblehat was trying to say was just that `it is very likely that your code does not do what you think it does, mainly because your code indentation is so poor that you cannot see what happens in which if-statement. Poorly indented code also tends to have missing brackets (or too many)`.

Comment: Oh and you may want to censor out your email address here, I missed that in my last edit ;)